# Sharing code between iOS and Android using Bazel and j2objc

Tags: android, ios, bazel, j2objc

I have a library with common code which uses `android.util.Log`:

```
java_library(
    name = "common",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
)
```

And I have an j2objc rule for iOS which works just fine:

```
j2objc_library(
    name = "common_ios",
    deps = ["//common"],
    jre_deps = ["@bazel_j2objc//:android_util_lib"],
)
```

But when I use `common` in my Android project:

```
android_binary(
    name = "app",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    manifest = "//android:manifest",
    resource_files = ["//android:resources"],
    deps = ["//common"],
)
```

But when I run `bazel build //android:app`, I get:

```
common/MyVeryOwnLogger.java:3: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.Log;
```

Which makes sense, as `android.*` libs should not be available in a `java_library` rule. Am I missing something? Is this not the recommended way to setup a project?

Thanks!

Comment: you may provide custom `android.util.Log` implementation or move `MyVeryOwnLogger` implementation out of common

Comment: @Selvin sure but then I'm not reusing code. The idea is to use the `android_util` library in iOS and the native `android.util` package in Android.

Comment: I would 1. create java_library called `android_util` with one file `android/util/Log.java` 2. adds it as `deps` (`deps = ["//common", "android_util"]`) in common_ios ...

Comment: The iOS code is working as intended. I probably didn't make that clear enough. You can see that it depends on `//common` but also `android_util_lib` for logging. The issue is that, on Android, the `//common` rule can't find `android.*` classes, even though it is depended on in an `android_binary` rule. This makes me think that my bazel setup is not following the correct practices. EDIT: added the bazel command which gives the error.

Answer (score 1):

A `java_library` won't be able to compile code that depends on Android because it won't have any of the Android dependencies that `android_library` provides.

Have you tried running your iOS app with a dependency on `common` that uses Android classes? I'm a little surprised that that works.

In any case, I recommend moving things that are platform dependent out of `common` and into platform-specific rules.

So, for example, say you have some kind of business logic `Model` class in `common` that requires a logger, create some interface like `Logger` in `common`, and have `Model` take an instance of `Logger`. Then you can have an `android_library` rule that depends on `common` and provides an implementation of `Logger` for Android that uses all the classes in `android.util.*`. Then your `android_binary` rule depends on both `common` and the `android_library`. In your app code, you can then instantiate an instance of the Android-specific logger and pass that to `Model`.

For the iOS half of things, you can similarly have an objective-c rule that provides iOS-specific logging (though I'm less familiar with how all that would work in objective-c or iOS).

You might also consider breaking up `common` into separate rules, which will improve incrementality (e.g. putting logging into its own rule). This all depends on the structure of your code.

Comment: The `j2objc_library` rule depends on `@bazel_j2objc//:android_util_lib` which is an implementation of a couple useful `android.*` classes made available by j2objc (see https://developers.google.com/j2objc/guides/required-link-flags#other_j2objc_libraries). On the Android side, there is obviously no need for such a reimplementation as the runtime has all of these classes available. So the issue is more of a "how do I tell this to bazel".

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll remove that bit from my answer since it's irrelevant. I think the clean solution to getting the `java_library` to compile is still to split it up into separate components, with the android parts in an `android_library`. A `java_library` on its own won't be able to compile android code. That said, it is possible to depend directly on `android.jar` using e.g. `@androidsdk//:platforms/android-25/android.jar`, however that won't be in sync with the `--android_sdk` flag.

Comment: There is, however, an undocumented rule you can use that does take into account `--android_sdk`:
```
java_import(
  name = "android_jar",
  jars = [":android_tools_defaults_jar"],
  neverlink = True,
)

android_tools_defaults_jar(
  name = "android_tools_defaults_jar"
)```

Comment: `android_tools_defaults_jar` is undocumented mostly because it's just used internally and we might want to get rid of it one day and replace it with an appropriate set of `config_setting`s + `select`s, but we have no immediate plans to do so as far as I know.

Comment: Also, in either case, you'll want to use a `java_import` with `neverlink = True` so that your code is only compiled against the classes in the jar, and they don't end up anywhere.

Comment: I'd still prefer not to depend on internal APIs. Tom Ball, from j2objc, suggested having the type of rule depend on which target is being built. Either put my code in an `android_library` or a `java_library` + `j2objc_library`. That's what I ended up doing and it's working fine, for now. Btw, thanks for telling me about `neverlink`!